# How do I close my question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

A while back, [I had some problems with a Java app receiving mouse focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962956/jpanel-not-receiving-mouse-events-on-mac).  I thought it was a problem with my code, but on later inspection all Java programs on my computer were having the same problem, and rebooting fixed it.  I don't know what was wrong, but hopefully it won't come back.

My understanding is at this point the question is supposed to be closed as "too localized" because it is a "[Question about a problem that can no longer be reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)...".  However, I've tried voting to close three times and the vote always just ages off.  Am I wrong about what should happen with my question?  Or how do I attract more close-voters?

Comment: Looks like this was taken care of...

Comment: the meta effect has taken care of closing it for you :-) It might not be a bad idea, though, to add a comment under the question explaining why it's no longer reproducible. If something like this happens to you again, you can visit the SOCVR (Close vote) Meta chat room and the folks there should help :-)

Comment: There is a comment (the second-to-last comment) it's just collapsed by default because there are too many comments on the question.

Comment: @CindyMeister Just so you know, in order to prevent conflicts of interest, SOCVR doesn't permit requests from people that are "involved" in the post they are making the request about. Users who are "involved" in a question are question author and the author of any non-deleted, non-community wiki answer. You can find more detail on that in [#15 in our FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-no-requests-youre-involved).

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed -- it's a how-to process question, not just a request to get it closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NB: Your post is currently/already closed now.

Normally when someone asks a question and then the question becomes off-topic later like this, we recommend deleting the question. However, you can't do that as the question has an upvoted answer, one of the [criteria preventing self-deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

In this case, it can be frustrating to try and effect a specific outcome that requires a group only to find your efforts keep aging away. This is one of the various bad things about [letting close votes age away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting).

As for getting the outcome you desire (e.g. a closed question)...

- You can continue to try to get the question closed as no repro the route you've been following (an edit to the question that it was resolved by rebooting would help less-attentive reviewers notice that the OP is requesting a closure of their own question and that it's truly a 'no repro' situation).
- Or you can ask a question on Meta requesting help here as you've done, which is typically pretty effective thanks to the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Comment: To be fair, I upvoted the answer, so I could have just un-upvoted it and deleted the question I guess...

Comment: @g.rocket Normally, yes, but in this case I'm betting you upvoted the answer a long time ago, so your vote is locked in. That means the answer would need to be edited in order for you to change your vote. Also normally not an issue, but you also don't have 2k reputation, meaning your edit would have to be approved by others. Suddenly it's not such a quick & easy workaround. :-)